# How to handle the onActivityResult() in viewPager2 child fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager2, android-jetpack-navigation

I had implemented Jetpack Navigation Component in my android app. There is an Tab fragment on nav host fragment where I had used viewPager2. When I open another activity from the child fragment of viewPager and navigate back from that activity then onActivityResult() of current child fragment not called.